# How to split numpy array into numpy arrays based on columns?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I want to split numpy array based on columns if all values of column are zero. If sequence of columns has only 0  like first two columns of sample array, this group should discard.

Is there any efficient solution?

Sample input numpy array:

```
[[0.   0.   0.   255.   0.   255.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   255.   0.   255.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   255.   0.   255.   255. 0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   255. 255.   0.   0.     0.   0.   255.]
 [0.   0.   0.   255.   0.   255.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   255.   0.   255.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   255.   0.   255.   0.   0.   0.  ]
]
```

Expected output numpy array:

```
[[
  [0.    255.]
  [0.    255.]
  [0.    255.]
  [255.  255.]
  [0.    255.]
  [0.    255.]
  [0.    255.]
 ]
 [
  [255. 0.  ]
  [255. 0.  ]
  [255. 255.]
  [0.   0.  ]
  [255. 0.  ]
  [255. 0.  ]
  [255. 0.  ]
 ]
 [
  [0.  ]
  [0.  ]
  [0.  ] 
  [255.] 
  [0.  ]
  [0.  ]
  [0.  ]
 ]
]
```

Comment: You want the output in a numpy array? If so what would the `shape()` be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `itertools.groupby` and list comprehension

```
from itertools import groupby

m = a.any(0)
out = [a[:,[*g]] for k, g in groupby(np.arange(len(m)), lambda x: m[x] != 0) if k]

Out[180]:
[array([[  0, 255],
        [  0, 255],
        [  0, 255],
        [255, 255],
        [  0, 255],
        [  0, 255],
        [  0, 255]]),
 array([[255,   0],
        [255,   0],
        [255, 255],
        [  0,   0],
        [255,   0],
        [255,   0],
        [255,   0]]),
 array([[  0],
        [  0],
        [  0],
        [255],
        [  0],
        [  0],
        [  0]])]
```

**Note**: `a` is your sample array

---

As in the comment, if you want to discard columns having only one non-zero value, you only need change `m` to different mask to handle both all `0` and `one non-zero`

```
m = (a != 0).sum(0) > 1    
out = [a[:,[*g]] for k, g in groupby(np.arange(len(m)), lambda x: m[x] != 0) if k]

Out[204]:
[array([[255],
        [255],
        [255],
        [255],
        [255],
        [255],
        [255]]),
 array([[255],
        [255],
        [255],
        [  0],
        [255],
        [255],
        [255]])]
```

Comment: It works as I expect, thanks! Is it possible if just one element of column is not equal to 0, can you say how I discard that column too?

Comment: like columns: `2, 6, 8` (counting from `0`). You want to discard them?

Comment: Yes, if just one value is different from 0.

Comment: You don't actually need additional mask, just change mask `m` to handle both `all zero` and `one non-zero`. Check my latest updated answer

Comment: What is ‘*g’? I’ve never seen that in python

Comment: @gnodab: it is `unpacking` operator of python. Read this https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/ for more info. `groupby` returns a tuple of key and iterator. So, `g` is an iterator. `[*g]` is unpacking iterator `g` to a list. It is equivalent to `list(g)`

Comment: @AndyL,Thanks! That is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to leverage the `scipy.ndimage` library to label columns with any non-zero elements, then split your array using those labels.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html

For example ...

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

# convert input string to numpy array
s = '''[[0.   0.   0.   255.   0.   255.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   255.   0.   255.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   255.   0.   255.   255. 0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   255. 255.   0.   0.     0.   0.   255.]
 [0.   0.   0.   255.   0.   255.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   255.   0.   255.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   255.   0.   255.   0.   0.   0.  ]
]'''
X = eval("np.array(%s)" % s.replace('.', ',').replace('\n', ',')).astype(float)

# label continuous columns with any non-zero values
labels, N = ndimage.label((X > 0).any(0))

# display the column splits
for n in range(1, N+1):
    mask = labels == n
    print(X[:, mask])
```

Should display ...

```
[[  0. 255.]
 [  0. 255.]
 [  0. 255.]
 [255. 255.]
 [  0. 255.]
 [  0. 255.]
 [  0. 255.]]
[[255.   0.]
 [255.   0.]
 [255. 255.]
 [  0.   0.]
 [255.   0.]
 [255.   0.]
 [255.   0.]]
[[  0.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]
 [255.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]]
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry because I forgot to say without scipy.

Answer (score 1):

If you can’t or don’t want to use scipy this also works:

```
def twoCols():
    arr = np.array([[0. ,  0.,   0.,   255. ,  0.,   255.,   0.  , 0. ,  0.  ],[0.  , 0. ,  0. ,  255. ,  0.,   255.,   0.  , 0. ,  0.  ],[0.,   0. ,  0.  , 255.,   0.  , 255. ,  255. ,0. ,  0.  ],[0.   ,0. ,  255., 255. ,  0. ,  0. ,    0. ,  0. ,  255.],[0.,   0. ,  0. ,  255. ,  0.,   255. ,  0. ,  0.,   0.  ],[0.,   0. ,  0. ,  255.,   0. ,  255. ,  0. ,  0.,   0.  ],[0.,   0. ,  0. ,  255. ,  0. ,  255. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.  ]], dtype=np.float64)
    arrs = []   
    for c in range(arr.shape[1]):
        if c == arr.shape[1]-1:
            if sum(arr[:,c]) > 0:
                    arrs.append(arr[:,c:])              
        elif sum(arr[:,c]) > 0 and sum(arr[:,c+1]) > 0:
            arrs.append(arr[:,c:c+2])                           
    return arrs

>>> twoCols()
[array([[   0.,  255.],
       [   0.,  255.],
       [   0.,  255.],
       [ 255.,  255.],
       [   0.,  255.],
       [   0.,  255.],
       [   0.,  255.]]), array([[ 255.,    0.],
       [ 255.,    0.],
       [ 255.,  255.],
       [   0.,    0.],
       [ 255.,    0.],
       [ 255.,    0.],
       [ 255.,    0.]]), array([[   0.],
       [   0.],
       [   0.],
       [ 255.],
       [   0.],
       [   0.],
       [   0.]])]
```

Comment: How can I access these arrays separately? 
'for _ in arrs' returns one dimensional arrays multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: arrs is just a regular python list, so you can access each array with arrs[0], arrs[1], etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is not in the same format you asked for. But I like the elegance:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([
 [0.,   0.,   0.,   255.,   0.,   255.,   0.,   0.,   0.  ],
 [0.,   0.,   0.,   255.,   0.,   255.,   0.,   0.,   0.  ],
 [0.,   0.,   0.,   255.,   0.,   255.,   255., 0.,   0.  ],
 [0.,   0.,   255., 255.,   0.,   0.,     0.,   0.,   255.],
 [0.,   0.,   0.,   255.,   0.,   255.,   0.,   0.,   0.  ],
 [0.,   0.,   0.,   255.,   0.,   255.,   0.,   0.,   0.  ],
 [0.,   0.,   0.,   255.,   0.,   255.,   0.,   0.,   0.  ],
])
```

```
a=np.zeros((data.shape[0]))            
cols = np.any(data!=0, axis=0)
for i, c in enumerate(cols):
    if c:
        a = np.column_stack((a, data[:,i]))
a = a[:,1:]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[  0. 255. 255.   0.   0.]
 [  0. 255. 255.   0.   0.]
 [  0. 255. 255. 255.   0.]
 [255. 255.   0.   0. 255.]
 [  0. 255. 255.   0.   0.]
 [  0. 255. 255.   0.   0.]
 [  0. 255. 255.   0.   0.]]
```